# INVALID_SERVICE upon firewall command

Tags: firewalld

Upon entering following command,

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql-13  --permanent
```

I am getting this

```
Error: INVALID_SERVICE: 'postgresql-13' not among existing services
```

Where, postgresql-13 is my service.

What must have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you [define a custom firewalld service](https://firewalld.org/documentation/howto/add-a-service.html) named `postgresql-13`? You didn't mention doing so.

Firewalld services define one or more ports and/or protocols to allow in the firewall. They are disjoint from systemd services.

If you wanted to enable incoming traffic to PostgreSQL, the correct service name is `postgresql`.

Answer (score 0):

`firewall-cmd --get-services` shows all services that *firewalld* is aware of. For every service listed, there's an XML file in */usr/lib/firewalld/services*. Consult it to find the ports that are actually being opened by enabling a service.

In the OP's case, there should be a file */usr/lib/firewalld/services/postgresql.xml* which defines port 5432/tcp.